# PageRank Algorithm on a Graph with a Sink Node

Tags: charts, computer-science, graph-theory, social-networking, pagerank

Assume that initially the value of each node is 1/4.

As we see here, the Node 3 is a Sink Node, and hence when the graph converges the value of each node tends to 0. How do we calculate the PageRank for graphs like these?

[Graph in Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t0ST.png)

In particular, the question is to find the value of each node after the second iteration of the algorithm. The options are as follows :

1. 0.25, 0.13, 0.25, 0.25
2. 0.25, 0.13, 0.19, 0.13
3. 0.13, 0.13, 0.19, 0.13
4. 0.13, 0.06, 0.13, 0.13

I have tried running the standard PageRank algorithm, and I am unable to get any output

Comment: I found out that they are called Dangling Nodes. How do I handle these?